# Modify active AWS Federated User Policy / Federated Token (AWSJavaSDK)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using this API to acquire federated tokens that will allow users to access certain AWS resources such as S3 Buckets, and directories inside that bucket ([AWSJavaSDK Get Federated Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/model/GetFederationTokenRequest.html)).

Is it possible to revoke certain aspects of their applied policy?  Let's say that this user has access to a certain directory upon initial policy creation then I want to revoke only partial access.  Is it possible to achieve this functionality without reissuing another token?  Below is a sample policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::productionapp"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::productionapp/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any other way to achieve what i'm going for here?

Answer (score 1):

Changing permissions assigned to the temporary credentials obtained from federated token API is only possible by changing the permissions of the IAM user who created it. That user must not be the root user because their permissions cannot be changed.

I'd probably use [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) to achieve it:

- Identify number of policies required. For instance there are four users A, B, C and D who will use the temporary credentials. After 1 hour, B and C will no longer have access to certain resources.
- So we need two IAM users one for group A & B and one for group B & C
- Create IAM users for each group of users identified for temporary credentials
- Create a Lambda function `GenerateTmpCredentials`. This function will generate 
  temporary credentials for each user group using their corresponding IAM user credentials
- Create another Lambda function `ChangePolicy`. This function will create new 
  policy for user group where partial access needs to be revoked and assign it to
  the IAM user of the corresponding user group
- Now wire it up in step functions workflow (state machine)

See the step functions state machine template for the above workflow

```
{
  "StartAt": "GenerateTmpCredentials",
  "States": {
    "GenerateTmpCredentials": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "<put arn of the GenerateTmpCredentials lambda>",
      "Next": "WaitOneHour"
    },
    "WaitOneHour": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 3600,
      "Next": "ChangePolicy"
    },
    "ChangePolicy": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "<put arn of the ChangePolicy lambda>",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Above workflow will first invoke the GenerateTmpCredentials function then wait 1 hour and after that it will invoke ChangePolicy policy function.

You can execute the state machine using API Gateway or any other Lambda based on your requirement.